# Logstash 6.0.0: Unknown setting ‘index_type’ for elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I'm trying to run logstash config files on ELK 6.0.0 docker image but I got this error:
Unknown setting 'index_type' for elasticsearch

I am retrieving Spark streaming stats and send it to elasticsearch, but even this simple task returns an error. Here is my code:

```
input {
  graphite {
    codec => "json"
    port => 10513
    host => "0.0.0.0"
  }
}

output {
  #stdout { codec => "json" }

  elasticsearch {
    codec => "json"
    hosts => "localhost"
    index => "spark-%{+YYYY.MM.DD}"
    index_type => "spark"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I got this error: Unknown setting 'index_type' for elasticsearch

The error means what it says. Your configuration has `index_type` within the elasticsearch output, but that is not a valid setting.

Logstash does not allow you to include settings that are not recognised.

Did you mean [`document_type`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.6/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-document_type) ?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is `document_type` not `index_type`:

```
  elasticsearch {
    codec => "json"
    hosts => "localhost"
    index => "spark-%{+YYYY.MM.DD}"
    document_type => "spark"          <--- change this
  }
```

Comment: I got the same error with this new configuration (Unknown setting ‘index_type’ for elasticsearch)

Comment: `Unknown setting ‘index_type’ for elasticsearch` means the setting is still named `index_type` not `document_type`